# Как скопировать изображение с веб сайта в буфер обмена python

Tags: python, web-scraping, веб-скрейпинг

Нужно скопировать картинку с сайта в буфер обмена.

Comment: сохранить на диск или именно в буфер обмена?

Comment: в буфер обмена.

Comment: и желательно сказать как потом вставить в сообщение discord.py

Comment: если с этого сайта если вставить ссылку на изображение, то оно не показывается

Comment: с какого "с этого"? ))

Comment: http://fapreactor.com/ nsfw контент

Comment: #хоспди, опять вы с этим сайтом... сохраните на сервер, отдайте в дискорт и удалите - так не пробовали?

Comment: я на heroku, там вроде бы запрещено записывать файлы. Я читал это в интернете.

Comment: если сервер с гифками настроет отдавать файл с проверкой заголовка или кукиз, то просто ссылка работать не будет, 500 или 403

Comment: А как это исправить? Если возможно.